# Extending @property.setter decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm writing multiple classes with a common logic added to a bunch of attributes. This is a simplified version of the code:

```py
class FooAspect:
  _bar_prop = 'bar'

  def __init__(self, bar_value: int):
    self._bar = bar_value

  @property
  def bar(self) -> int:
    return self._bar

  @bar.setter
  def bar(self, value: int) -> None:
    self._bar = value

    perfrom_action(self._bar_prop, value)
```

`perform_action` always has similar form, and I would like to encapsulate it with a decorator. Essentially I'm looking for a way to write something like this:

```py
# ... define @my_setter

class FooAspect:
  # ...

  @property
  def bar(self) -> int:
    return self._bar

  @bar.my_setter(key='bar')
  def bar(self, value: int) -> None:
    self._bar = value
```

Is it possible to extend `@property` or `@prop.setter` to achieve this?

Comment: You should probably just write your own descriptor, instead of trying to extend `property` The whole point or `property` is to give you an implementation of a very common use-case, for more complicated things, *you should just write your own descriptor*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think about it! I still would like to extend `property` (or implement my own version, but I'm not sure through which mechanism it works, it's different from simple decorators I've used before) because it would allow keeping all the things related to the attribute close together in the code.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I mean by "implement your own descriptor". The fact that it is a *decorator* is not really relevant. That isn't how it fundamentally works, it works because the decorator returns a descriptor object.

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga! This is exactly what I needed. I managed to implement the behavior I needed and posted the answer below.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What the OP asks for is to perform additional functionalities on top of what the `property` class already does, exactly what class inheritance is intended for. I've included such an implementation for reference.

Comment: @blhsing sure, but my point is you *don't really need the property behavior*, most of which is to allow for one-off implementations of getters and setters, if the behavior is truly common across classes. So, I've given an example of what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While copying and pasting the reference code of `property` and making minor modifications would work as demonstrated by your answer, in the interest of code reuse you can subclass the `property` class and call `super()` to access methods of the parent class instead.

Also, the `setter` function in your implementation is unnecessarily instantiating a new instance of `MyProperty`, when it can reuse the current object by returning `self._setter`:

```
class MyProperty(property):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        super().__set__(obj, value)
        perform_action(self.key, value)

    def _setter(self, fset):
        obj = super().setter(fset)
        obj.key = self.key
        return obj

    def setter(self, key):
        self.key = key
        return self._setter
```

so that:

```
class FooAspect:
    @MyProperty
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter(key='bar')
    def bar(self, value: int) -> None:
        self._bar = value

def perform_action(key, value):
    print(key, value)

f = FooAspect()
f.bar = 'foo'
```

outputs:

```
bar foo
```

Answer (score 4):

My point wasn't to copy the `property` implementation, that is *very generic on purpose*, which probably isn't needed if your logic is always the same for your getter and setter. So it would be better to do something like:

```
def perform_action(key, value):
    print(key, value)

class PerformKeyAction:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # maybe common getter behavior
        return getattr(instance, self.attr_name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        perform_action(self.key, value)
        return setattr(instance, self.attr_name, value)

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.attr_name = f'_{name}'

class FooAspect:
    bar = PerformAction(key='bar')

class BazAspect:
    buzz = PerformAction(key='buzz_key')

class FizzAspect:
    fang = PerformAction(key='fang_key')
```

And this way you avoid the boilerplate *when writing your various classes* instead of repeating it in various getters/setters in various classes.

Comment: Well, actually what happens in getter/setter is not generalizable (I used simple hidden field access for simplicity), so subclassing `property` works better for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga I came up with this solution implementing my own descriptor:

```py
# myproperty.py

class MyProperty:
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, key=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.key = key

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")

        perfrom_action(self.key, value)

        self.fset(obj, value)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.key)

    def _setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.key)

    def setter(self, key):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, key=key)._setter
```

```py
# foo_aspect.py

from myproperty import MyProperty

class FooAspect:
  # ...

  @MyProperty
  def bar(self) -> int:
    return self._bar

  @bar.setter(key='bar')
  def bar(self, value: int) -> None:
    self._bar = value
```